# What is the history of the perfect active participle in Latin?

Tags: language-evolution, participle

From [this answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/804/12) and [Allen & Greenough §493](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q7cAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA310), I understand that Latin does not have a perfect active participle.  But on Wiktionary, I see the following usage note in the [entry on the suffix *-vus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-vus#Latin):

> Originally forming the perfect active participle, as in alvus ‎(“entity having nourished”), clīvus ‎(“entity having leaned”), gnāvus ‎(“having known”).

It's not clear if this is meant to suggest that Latin had a perfect active participle at one point, or if it only existed in Proto-Indo-European.

What is the history of the perfect active participle in Latin?  Did Classical Latin or Old Latin ever have such a thing, or did it die out in Proto-Italic or prior?

Comment: I've heard deponent perfect participles described as "active" before (like *locutus* or *hortatus*), but that doesn't seem relevant to the PIE question.

Answer (score 7):

Wiktionary seems to be wrong. De Vaan derives *clīvus* and *gnāvus* from forms with the PIE suffix *-wo-, which is not the same as the pf. ppl. suffix *-wos-; he derives *alvus* by metathesis from an earlier *aulos*. Weiss lists the first two along with many others under nouns formed with the suffix -uo-.

The PIE perfect participle was athematic and had *-wōs in the masc. nom. sg. It's hard to see how such a form would end up in the Latin second declension; you'd expect a paradigm ending in -ōs, -uris, or perhaps by analogy looking like *flōs, flōris* or *honor, honōris*.

Comment: Are there any Latin words that do contain the perfect participle suffix?

Comment: Can this be extended generally to say, then, that no form of Latin ever had a present active participle?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Not to my knowledge; I can't think of any likely candidates, anyway.

Comment: @Nathaniel I believe so. I don't think the other Italic languages have any vestige of such a form either, though I could be wrong about that.

Comment: @Hugh I should have said "perfect" rather than "present" in my Aug 31 comment for consistency.  My understanding is that they are related, but I shouldn't have confused things here.